# obj file loader in javafx gives a transparent mesh

Tags: javafx-8

I am trying to write an obj loader in javafx, but despite enabling deptTest in the scene constructor the result is transparent

```
public View() throws Exception {
    meshView = createSimplex();

    Group axisGroup = buildAxes();          
    createBoundBoxAndSetBounds( meshView);            
    Group group = new Group();

    group.getTransforms().addAll(rotateZ, rotateY, rotateX);
    group.setDepthTest(DepthTest.ENABLE);

    scene = new Scene(group, 640, 480,true,SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);

    float w = abs(maxy - miny);
    float alpha = (0.5f / (w / (float) scene.getHeight()));

    PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
    camera.setNearClip(0.1);
    camera.setFarClip(5000.0);
    camera.setTranslateZ(-1000);


    scene.setCamera(camera);

    group.getChildren().addAll(meshView);

    handleMouseEvents();

}
```

Result of loading:

[image]

What could be wrong?

Comment: To me this seems like the `cullFace` property is set to the wrong value... Try setting it to `BACK`, if it's `FRONT` and the other way round or simply disabling culling for testing and setting it to `NONE` (this makes the drawing operation less efficient though)...

Comment: i set culling to NONE and now it's all black

Comment: ok, it works now, i turned culling to NONE and added a light source. i think its because there is no normals in the obj file which help in determining the front faces from the back ones. thanks for your help